# Calculating incidence of unique tuples in a list of tuples

Tags: python, django

For a classifieds Django website project, I have a list of tuples made up of `(user_id, ad_id)` pairs. This denotes the clicker's `user_id`, alongwith the relevant `ad_id`.

For example:

```
gross_clicks = [(1, 13),(1, 12), (1, 13), (2, 45), (2, 13), (1, 15), ...(n, m)]
```

The elements in this list are by no means unique - each click gets pushed into this list regardless of whether it's by the same user and/or it's on the same ad.

Now I can get all unique clicks by doing:

```
unique_clicks = []
import operator
gross_click_ids = map(operator.itemgetter(0), gross_clicks)
return len(set(gross_click_ids))
```

But how do I get **unique clicks per ad**? I.e. if same user clicked on two different ads, that would be counted as 2 separate clicks.

Performance matters too - it's a large data set - so would prefer the most efficient solution, alongwith an illustrative example.

Comment: Instead of doing this in Python, why not do this at the database level? This will probably be faster.

Comment: I was thinking the same. It will be easier too.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: my backend is `Redis`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take unique tuples:

```
unique_clicks = set(gross_clicks)
```

This gives you the set of unique user impressions per ad.

In your sample input, `(1, 13)` appears twice, but in a set it would appear just once:

```
>>> gross_clicks = [(1, 13), (1, 12), (1, 13), (2, 45), (2, 13), (1, 15)]
>>> set(gross_clicks)
{(1, 12), (1, 13), (1, 15), (2, 45), (2, 13)}
```

Using sets to track unique elements is as efficient as it can get, given a large list of tuples as input (testing if any given tuple is already in the set is a O(1) constant time operation).

However, if this data came from your database, it is more efficient to ask *it* to give you unique pairs instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `distinct` method on the queryset instead. Let's say your model is `User` and you want to get unique `user_id`, `ad_id` pairs.

```
User.objects.all().values_list('id', 'ad_id').distinct('id', 'ad_id')
```

This performs the work on the database level, so I expect it would be faster than doing it in Python as Willem mentioned.

I *may* have misunderstood your question. Please let me know if that's the case so I can try to provide an alternate solution.